# Rolled back SSL config but server still broken

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, centos7

Access server through IP:
/var/www/ip/

Access server through Domain:
/var/www/domain/

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
DocumentRoot "/var/www/ip"
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain"
ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

After activating SSL with letsencrypt, server was returning 404 for any domain subfolder file. So I rolled back everything.

I used MELD to compare the /etc/httpd files and directory structure, everything is like before.

But it doesn't work like before. Access through ip returns 404 on /var/www/ip files.

I restarted apache, the server, what config files am I missing that I need to revert? /Conf.d/ already checked.

Comment: I know this doesn't help now, but this is a good example of why you should version control your configuration.

Comment: Go and check your shell history. As it seems you did perform more actions than you think. Also make sure that the restart really works. (Stop the server, check if it's gone, start the server)

Answer (score 1):

It's always good idea to check the logs for any errors. In the section above, you define the document root for both 'standard' and another one for your virtual host.

I believe you may have a conflict in the configuration ... virtual host is applied to anything on port 80 and document root `/var/www/ip`.

Perhaps the virutal host 'takes over' and points your apache to different folder than you expect. Are there files in that folder (`/var/www/domain`). If you want to serve both folders, you should probably put them into separate virtual hosts (you can define virtual host for name, port or combination of both).